# How to change the size of all types of text?

Tags: text-decorations, text-manipulation

I am fairly new to latex, but when I started writing my document, I noticed that the text was very small (from the normal text I used in paragraphs to the text I used to name different sections).

My question is, is there a way to make all of your text bigger for some amount of % (not just by a certain number of pixels)?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Be prepared that you have to rethink your present conceptions about how a document should look. As a first step become familiar with the documentclass of your document.

Comment: I am using an article document class

Comment: To change the fontsize you can set either `10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt` as an optional argument of the documentclass

Comment: These are the only three options?

Comment: Yes. However the reader of your document will be grateful for this limitation. Don't even try to question common typographical standards :)

Comment: Try `\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}` for instance, But yes, `12pt`  in `article` class  should be enough in most cases. Run `texdoc extsizes` for more information.

Comment: Are you wanting to change the ratio between the main text and that used for sectional headings?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the fontsize in the optional arguments of the documentclass:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
```

See [wikibooks/LaTeX/Document Structure](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Document_classes):

> 10pt, 11pt, 12pt  Sets the size of the main font in the document. If
>   no option is specified, 10pt is assumed.